# splitting a StringBuilder value without String.split()

Tags: java, regex, string, split, stringbuilder

I'll be processing texts and will split along the way for one, its substrings on regular expressions like [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) does. i'm looking to do these on [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for speed concerns.

From what i know, StringBuilder has no such method. all i can do is to invoke [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and turn the result into [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) []. 
however, this would be slow-- [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) interns every entry of String[] it produces.

Also - [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) isn't overriding [Object.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). when i need to use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as the type in collections, 
i'm writing a wrapper class that has a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) value-field and overriding [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) on the values of this field to get it right.

these are the 2 so far i can recall that i needed to have and that came short.

My Q is:

Am i missing something here - is there a way to get these functionalities on [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) without having String in between to slow it down?

If not - why not? The main reason-for-being of [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is the execution time at the cost of memory-- as alternative to String's efficient memory with slow execution(?) 
And [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a type for texts. why wouldn't it have these directly-- split() for one?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringBuilder is a CharSequence too.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",\\s*"); // Best static final.
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(stringBuilder);
int pos0 = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    int pos1 = m.start();
    CharSequence cs = stringBuilder.subSequence(pos0, pos1);
    ...
    pos0 = pos1;
}
CharSequence cs = stringBuilder.subSequence(pos0, stringBuilder.length());
...
```

Of course `s` being either CharSequence or String. A String could utilize `String.substring` which does not allocate a new char array.

A regular expression still is slow.

Comment: this would by=pass interning and looks ok. String.split()  has faster implementation when the reg.expression is just 1-char. any idea why StringBuilder is "slim" on these, an equals() for one to serve the purpose?

Comment: Could you rephrase "any idea why.."?

Comment: one wd expect StringBuilder overriding equals() for one. read my lines on using StringBuilder as the type of the entries in a collection. StringBuilder is most likely to be useful on the values of its text entry. however, it's equals() is "judging" the instances on their memory references-- not the text values. this is like java.lang.Integer not overriding equals-- which luckily isn't the case.

Comment: Yes, though having several StringBuilders, possibly wrapped in its own class with an equals, seems unnecessary. If `s` is a String, substrings will do nicely (fast and compact).

Comment: i dont understand your last comment. the substring() returns Strings and they're interned. interning is the thing that slows down the String at runtime. and, how would you use StringBuilder in a collection, say HashMap<StringBuilder> without a proper equals() to work it?

Comment: `substring  maintains a link to the original string's char array using a slice. `intern()` (storing the string in the constant pool) is never done automatically So I think Strings are not so bad. (As opposed to C++ `std::string`) Measure. But, yeah, if you want to use / tr out StringBuillder I think you are doing it right.Maybe `StringBuilder.subSequence` might be used.

Comment: yeah - subsequence and Pattern/Matcher wd do. i'll ask equals() separately.

Comment: `stringBuilder.subsequence(...)` doesn't exist. Should be `stringBuilder.subSequence(...)`